# In Android How can I draw a line in the same location on another screen with a different resolution?

Tags: android, canvas

I am communicating coordinates when drawing canvas using tcp socket, but coordinates are taken elsewhere when the resolution is different. How do I get to the same location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear on how good your results are so far. Also, I'm assuming that you have control over the sending of this data. If you're only receiving the data that you have no control over, this solution won't work. If you're correctly communicating a position between devices, then the hard part is done. You just have to do some math in the code before and after sending now to adjust for various device resolutions. Instead of passing strict pixel positioning, pass the ratio of pixel position to total canvas height/width.  Then when you receive the data, convert that back with the new resolution.

Please note that I said canvas and not screen height/width, since not all devices keep the same aspect ratio.  You may want to fit that canvas into the screens with a known aspect ratio to keep the converted image from stretching.